# Display a value from "data" inside donut chart - AmCharts

Tags: charts, pie-chart, amcharts, donut-chart

I´m trying to display a dynamic value (from backend) inside the inner radius of a pie donut chart (typically a percentage value).
Can you help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a label into [allLabels](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#allLabels). The other option is to [add the label](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#addLabel) after the chart initiated:

```
chart.addListener("init", function (e) {
    e.chart.addLabel(...);
});
```

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "pie",
    "theme": "light",
    "innerRadius": "40%",
    "gradientRatio": [-0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0, -0.2, -0.5],
    "dataProvider": [{
        "country": "Lithuania",
        "litres": 501.9
    }, {
        "country": "Czech Republic",
        "litres": 301.9
    }, {
        "country": "Ireland",
        "litres": 201.1
    }, {
        "country": "Germany",
        "litres": 165.8
    }, {
        "country": "Australia",
        "litres": 139.9
    }, {
        "country": "Austria",
        "litres": 128.3
    }],
    "balloonText": "[[value]]",
    "valueField": "litres",
    "titleField": "country",
    "balloon": {
        "drop": true,
        "adjustBorderColor": false,
        "color": "#FFFFFF",
        "fontSize": 16
    },
  "allLabels": [{
    "y": "47%",
    "align": "center",
    "size": 20,
    "bold": true,
    "color": "#555",
    "text": "30%"
  }],
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width  : 100%;
 height  : 500px;
 font-size : 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: "text": "30%" is a static value, i need to put inside a chart a "dynamic" value, mapped from JS backend